# In Creating Content, how do I add a line in the text?

Tags: content-manager

I am trying to add a line to my text to add some style. I want a title basically with a line above and a line below. There is a function in the top bar to add a horizontal line however there are no editing features for the line once it is there. I was wondering if anyone has any tricks or tips. THANKS!

---

[image]

This is the editing area I am using, I want to be able to edit the line that's there under my name in the text box. Is this the "simple" editing you mentioned?

Comment: What type of field is it? A rich text field can do this easily, but a "simple" text field not really...

Comment: Moderator's note: I converted your answer to an edit to better fit the [Q&A format of Tridion Stack Exchange](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: No problem Alvin. I've realized since that I was using the wrong content option for what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

As Nuno highlighted in the comment, only RTF will offer you to insert a horizontal line in the design tab of the component. Tridion just inserts a `<hr/>` tag to the source of the RTF.

If you do have a Rich Text Field defined in your schema (with source formatting feature enabled), you can add supported HTML attributes directly to it, in the source tab of your RTF field. If you are having a custom style in the CSS of the page, it can be referred too as well in the source of the component but the change will only be visible when you publish the page.

If you feel that you need more tips and tricks, you would need to add more details to your question so that the community can address it. Thanks!

Comment: okay so how would I go about setting the field to the right settings to have more ability to edit. A good example of what I am trying to do: if you make a line across a word document with minus signs and hit enter it automatically creates a line. I want to be able to do that on my page in the SDL editor more easily.

Comment: I believe you mean the `hr` tag as in "horizontal rule," rather than `tr` (table row).

Comment: I have corrected the typo @AlvinReyes..

Comment: @Chris94, It is important to understand that rich text fields are stored as XHTML in Tridion and cleaned up using HtmlTidy. You can use the options suggested by Alvin. Rich text is intended to provide a friendly authoring experience for publishers and not intended to replicate any editor's functionality, described above.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Treat the horizontal rule (`<hr/>`) as a character.

- Click before it and press <kbd>delete</kbd> to remove it
- Click after it and press <kbd>backspace</kbd> after it

You can also use cut, copy, and paste when selecting the text around a horizontal rule.

**Note**: in Experience Manager, the horizontal rule is in the `Insert > Symbols` part of the ribbon toolbar.

---

**Edit**: the following applies to tables, images, and hyperlinks but don't help much with the horizontal rule, aside from maybe showing it exists in the rich text.

To re-edit *other* "insertable" elements, highlight or *select* them and press the command button again (e.g. editing a link or image that's already been inserted).

- To help with selection, the `Current Elements` drop-down shows the elements detected in the rich text. Navigate nodes in the drop-down to find either an element or its containing parent node.

[image: Current Element drop-down in the ribbon toolbar's section part]

- And `Section Type` lets you change the selected element (doesn't apply for `<hr/>`).

[image: Section Type drop-down in the ribbon toolbar's section part]

**Tip**: `Body Text` will remove a wrapping element.

*Images are from SDL Docs.*

Refer to the docs for [more information on rich text editing](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-B3A37F10-6A91-4BD7-A0BB-27A173F08C6F).

Comment: +1 for adding experience manager and calling out scope of Section Type and Current Elements as well.